# WPF - Binding to dll function

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dll

How can I bind ListBox that show all items in `ObservableCollection` that return by a function in some dll?

I have in the dll singltone class called `FilesManager` and a function `Instance()` that return the pointer to this class. Then I have function that called `GetFiles()`, its returns `ObservableCollection` that contains all the files names.

And I have a ListBox in xml and I want to bind it `ItemsSource` property to
`FilesManager.Instance().GetFiles()`, How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the MVVM design pattern. In this case, you would have a property on your view model that exposes the `FilesManager.Instance().GetFiles()` collection, and your view would bind to this property.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.Files = FilesManager.Instance().GetFiles();
    }

    public XXX Files { get; private set; }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" ... />
```

If you wanted to change the `Files` reference after construction, you would need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update the UI.

Comment: The property must to be as `DependencyProperty`

Comment: No it doesn't, INotifyPropertyChanged would be the correct way to do any UI update notifications from a view model. Your view models should not be dependency objects.

Comment: Hmm..? But `ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"` worked only if `Files` is dependency property...

Comment: No, that's only true of the binding target - in this case the ItemsSource property of the ListBox.

Comment: The property defined in the window .cs file, right? If I write `ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"` in the XAML, the binding not works if `Files` is not dependency property (propdp snippt)...

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms752347.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28174/discussion-between-someone-and-devdigital)